# Potential database systems for portable/standalone web applications?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, web-applications

I'm in the process of developing a portable web app using python/cherrypy, which I'd like to ideally be able to simply extract to a folder and not have to install anything. One of the things potentially preventing this is my database back end. Most similar set ups seem to use SQLite, however I have a few concerns, as I may have up to 30 people connected to my server at once and am worried the write exclusive locks will have a large impact.

My questions:

1. How badly will SQLite struggle with handling up to 30 connections attempting to read, with a few of those attempting to write, at the same time? What kind of wait time might an insert cause for people trying to read from the database?
2. Does anyone have any alternative suggestions? I'd like to avoid MySQL as I have some commercial aspirations for my project, though if it's necessary I'll go down that route. I'd probably give up full portability and require a PostgreSQL install before I commit to MySQL though....
3. Is it plausible to have a single desktop serving that many connections as long as bandwidth isn't an issue?

Thanks in advance for your help, and apologies if I'm asking anything obvious or that's been answered previously (I've spent a decent amount of time searching on here/online and haven't seen anything definitive).
-repole

EDIT: By the way, some useful discussion [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/386885-free-small-stand-alone-database/) for anyone who stumbles upon this question later.

Comment: Depending on the use case, why don't you also think about NoSQL databases?

Comment: @Cinquo - I have pretty much 0 understanding of NoSQL databases. I'm currently looking into them. For what it's worth my database is to be very relation dependent, my current design features a foreign key in pretty much every table; from what I'm reading early on with NoSQL, it may not be an ideal solution for that.



@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - I'd like someone to be able to copy and paste their folder containing my application to another computer and use it as if nothing has changed. I've seen a number of web apps that are capable of this (SABnzbd, SickBeard, Subsonic to name a few).

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - Regardless of where the application is being run from, multiple users need to be able to connect to it. An example of this is Subsonic (a music/video streaming web app), which I'm currently running off of an external hard drive as a web application, and can be connected to by multiple users. "Need" might not be the right word, but it's something I'd like to be able to accomplish because of the versatility it adds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some pure python databases out there, not sure how good or stable they are:

- [PyDbLite](http://www.pydblite.net/en/PyDbLite.html)
- [BuzHug](http://buzhug.sourceforge.net/)
- [SnakeSQL](http://pythonweb.org/projects/snakesql/)
- [KirbyBase](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/KirbyBase/1.9)

If you are worried about licenses for distribution, then check out stuff with an Apache license. One of the currently hosted top tier database projects is CouchDB. Main issue I see is that distribution is not as easy as simply including a Python module.

Not sure what the architecture is like on your web app, but multiple Sqlite  databases could be used to get around the locking issue.

Another option is Berkeley DB: http://docs.python.org/library/bsddb.html

Comment: As mentioned in my comment above, I'm not overly familiar with NoSQL solutions. I'll certainly look into CouchDB (and other NoSQL solutions).

Not sure if multiple SQLite databases would work, I suppose I could make a separate database for essentially each user, there would be some occasional swapping of information between each separate file, but I that would be more efficient than a single database I'd think.

Comment: Another non-network based database is Berkeley DB (which can support thousands of simultaneous threads accessing the same database): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB

Comment: Added some pure python databases to the answer. If performance isn't an issue (30 users doesn't seem like it would, depending on usage) then these might do it.

Comment: really appreciate the follow up. I'll spend a few hours looking into these options today.